# Errorbars in a Clustered Histogram

Tags: gnuplot

I am trying to get my output file to be a clustered histogram with error bars. However, I'm not sure how to do that, and the documentation hasn't helped too much (and neither have other stack exchange questions).

Here is my plot file:

```
set style histogram errorbars gap 1
set style data histogram
set style histogram cluster gap 1

set xtics ("first" 0, "second" 1, "third" 2,)

set style fill solid border rgb "black"
set auto x
set yrange [0:3.5]

plot 'output.dat' every 3 using 2:3 t "first", \
        '' every 3::1 using 2:3 t "second", \
    '' every 3::2 using 2:3 t "third",

pause -1 "button"
```

It doesn't seem to like the 2:3 selection.

The reason I'm doing that is because my data file is:

```
1 2.9556583767110065 0.1543917726747003 
2 0.5975194396247037 0.08924657791964963 
3 1.0168269230769227 0.17650174663307563 
4 0.5998971788445482 0.08937900729764456 
5 3.303322408585563 0.1924290159644262 
6 3.3220581501831505 0.22706769012042347 
7 0.5725853094274155 0.09841846909260431 
8 1.8532228005912212 0.1253003804660912 
9 1.3025984432234434 0.1684290316839671
```

In which the first column, is the Line Number
The second column is the mean/count.
The third column is the standard deviation.

Now, what I get if I remove the 2:3 selection is the following graph: 
[image: Graph]

Which is exactly what I want, but no Error Bras.

If somebody could help explain the correct way to do this, and why my way doesn't work (and why the correct way does), that would be very appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: One of those too-obvious-to-see errors.  Your first command `set style histogram errorbars gap 1` is correct, but then you undo it by setting the histogram style to `clustered` instead.  Remove the second `set style histogram` command and all is well.

Comment: Thank you, that did solve my problem.